# GDI+ font fallback not working for emojis

Tags: windows, unicode, gdi+

In our app we draw text using GDI+ (`Graphics::DrawString()`). We're using a clone of a `StringFormat::GenericTypographic()` string format with `StringFormatFlagsMeasureTrailingSpaces` as the only additional flag. `StringFormatFlagsNoFontFallback` is definitely not set in the format.

This all works great, except for emojis when the selected font doesn't include the emoji glyph. My expectation is that GDI+ will fall back on a font that does have this glyph (e.g. Segoe UI Emoji), however this doesn't seem to be working. If we manually switch to Segoe UI Emoji then all the emojis render correctly.

This is on Windows 10.

Comment: Font fallback has very hairy and poorly documented implementation details.  But sure, it isn't very likely that it considers fallback for a TrueType font (all that GDI+ supports) to an OpenType font.  Rendering text with GDI+ is pretty universally avoided, most notably in .NET which substituted Graphics.DrawString with TextRenderer.DrawText.  DrawTextEx() under the hood.